# Is it possible to listen to native Android broadcast events in Angular.js

Tags: android, angularjs

I am planning to integrate smart barcode scanner to my angular.js based app, the device is like a PDA(smartphone like with built in scanner).
I asked the device's manufacturer technical team and they are saying that it generates Android broadcast events.
Now I want to ask that is it possible to listen to native broadcast event in browser running my angular.js application, if yes, then how?